# Fluent Validation как передать значение идентификатора сущности во все ошибки

Tags: asp.net, валидация

Столкнулся с проблемой создания валидатора

Имеются классы

```
public class Lists
{
        public List<List> List{ get; set; }
}
```

```
public class List
{
        public string? Id { get; set; }
        public string? Number { get; set; }
        public string? Data { get; set; }

}
```

Классы валидатора

```
public class ListsValidator : AbstractValidator<Lists>
{
        public ListsValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.List).NotEmpty();
            RuleForEach(x => x.List).SetValidator(new ListValidator());
        }
}
```

```
public class ListValidator : AbstractValidator<List>
{
    public ListValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Number )
                .NotEmpty().WithMessage(x => $"Number не может быть пустым или null");
        RuleFor(x => x.Data )
                .NotEmpty().WithMessage(x => $"Data не может быть пустым или null");

    }
}
```

Как я могу вставить во все сообщения об ошибках List.Id?
.WithMessage(x => $"Ошибка произошла в {List.Id}. Number не может быть пустым или null");

Comment: `x.Id` - вот нужное значение

Comment: Уж сколько раз твердили миру... Дайте нормальные имена сущностям! Ваш класс с тремя свойствами должен зваться наподобие `Item` или `Element`. Класс `Lists` совсем не нужен. Используйте напрямую `List<Item>`.